# I have trouble copying ArrayBuffers without corruption in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, copy, arraybuffer

I have some Javascript running in NodeJS trying to take some data coming in on a UDP port (local port), and collect it into bigger chunks before sending it on as this_block.

at top of file

```
var first_buf = new Uint8Array(1024*1024);
```

then later on

```
var newbox = get_box(view, last_offset, first_len);
if (newbox['type']=='abcd') {
    buf = view.slice(0, last_offset+newbox['length']);
    this_block = Array.prototype.slice.call(buf);
    buf = view.slice(last_offset+newbox['length'], first_len);
    // adjust first len to account for rest of data
    first_len = first_len - last_offset - newbox['length'];
    // and copy that data into the start of first_buf
    first_buf.set(buf);
    last_offset = 0;
}
else {
    this_block = [];
    buf = view.slice(0, first_len);
    // now copy this into the start of first_buf.
    first_buf.set(buf);
    // first_len is already set correctly, so don't need to adjust

    last_offset += newbox['length'];
}
```

So by the end of this, I should have this_block set to either an empty array or the correct arraybuffer to send.  It works, for a time, copying data to this_block, and copying any spare to the start of first_buf. And then after a few iterations the block copy (first_buf.set) corrupts the data and I get garbage.  I think it's the .set that is causing it, but I cannot see how.  Any clues gratefully received.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I don't think it's here that the problem lies.  Further analysis suggests that the data coming in is occasionally losing a chunk.